# Add prefix to url, but products not showing in page SHOP

Tags: menus, permalinks, pages, url-rewriting, urls

I have managed to add a prefix in the url of my site, now my site allows entering the Shop page with these two urls:
misitio.com/tienda

and with the prefix:
misitio.com/us/tienda

When I enter with the first URL everything works correctly, the categories and products are displayed on the SHOP page. (see image 1)

But when I enter with the second URL, it only shows me the categories (see image 2)

The strange thing is that when I enter with the URL2 and enter a category the products are shown (see figure).

I need your help so that when I enter URL2 the categories and products are displayed as it happens when I enter URL1.

It will be a problem with woocommerce or I am missing something to do.

The prefix I have done by changing by rewriting the rules in the structure of the page in function.php. thanks for your support.
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I use the following code to add the prefix:

```
add_action('init','change__permalinks');
function change_permalinks() {
 global $wp_rewrite;
 $prefix = 'us';
 $wp_rewrite -> use_trailing_slashes = false;
 $wp_rewrite -> $prefix . $wp_rewrite -> page_structure.'/%pagename%';
 $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
}
```